# Shell Script Error: "aliased to fprintf.cName.ksh[324] 121234 IOT/Abort"

Tags: unix

My Shell script Name.ksh was running fine.

Now the same script is throwing error **aliased to fprintf.cName.ksh[324]  121234 IOT/Abort**

What does this error code mean ?

Answer (score 0):

What I found that, This error is because of "No more space in the file System."